# Proving inequalities (2)

Tags: inequality

Given that $n>i$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_ix_{i+1} = 1 $, what is the largest value of $|x_k|$?

I multiplied the equation by 2 then rearranged the terms,

$x^2_1+(x_1+x_2)^2 + (x_2+x_3)^2 ... (x_{n-1} + x_n)^2 + x_n = 2$

After this I think we will use the Quadratic Mean > Arithmetic Mean?

$\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2 ... (x_{n-1}+x_n)}/\sqrt{n} > \frac{x_1+x_2...x_n}{n}$

I don't know how to move forward from this,

Comment: You should have a square on the $x_n$ term.  Should it be $n \gt 1$ in the first line?  $i$ is a dummy variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't prove it, but we can let $x_1$ be as large as possible and step down evenly so that all the other squares are the same size.  Specifically, let $$x_i=\pm \frac {n-i+1}nx_1$$ where the even terms are negative and the odd terms are positive.  All the squares after the first are $(\frac {x_1}{n})^2$ so our equation becomes 
$$x_1^2+(n-1)\frac {x_1^2}{n^2}=2\\x_1^2=\frac {2n^2}{n^2+n-1}\\
x_1=\sqrt{\frac {2n^2}{n^2+n-1}}$$
Which starts about $1.265$ for $n=2$ and rises to $\sqrt 2$ as $n\to \infty$